# Tutorial 1.2.1 Using rosmake

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just started the Tutorials and the 'rosmake beginner_tutorials' command gives me this output:

[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['beginner_tutorials']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/ryan/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120314-092824
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['beginner_tutorials'] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['beginner_tutorials']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

According to the tutorial I should have something like this:

[ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['beginner_tutorials']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/dbking/.ros/rosmake_output-2009-09-22-03-17-14
[ rosmake ] [ 0 of 18  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> genmsg_cpp >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< genmsg_cpp <<< [PASS] [ 0.39 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 1 of 18  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> roslib >>> [ make ]
...
...
...
[ rosmake ] [ 17 of 18  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> beginner_tutorials >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< beginner_tutorials <<< [PASS] [ 0.79 seconds ]

I thought I had followed everything up to this point successfully, but I can't seem to find the problem.  Any thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29695/tutorial-1.2.1-using-rosmake/) by [RyanG](https://answers.ros.org/users/1969/ryang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't seem to have beginner_tutorials in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

You should probably add this line to your ~/.bashrc (after the line which sources the ros setup.bash):

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/path/to/beginner_tutorials:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}
```

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2012-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3